# Device or material that is (near) 100% transparent from one side and (near) 100% reflective from the other side?

Tags: optics, reflection

Looking out of the window at night from a lit room, you see yourself reflected in the window and, depending on the lightness or darkness outside, you also see things outside. We can say:

> Some light from the inside is reflected and some light from the outside comes in.

Is it physically (and technically) possible to have a "window" screen for which the the two 'some' in the sentence above can be changed to 'all', as in the diagram?

[image]

- Light from the left passes through 100%, independent of angle.
- Light from the right is reflected 100%, independent of angle.

I wonder if this is possible and if yes, if there exist technical solutions, or whether some physical principle prevents this?

Comment: I don't suppose that a video camera & screen counts as a valid technical solution? ;)

Comment: Nice workaround:-) But no, I'd rather learn about some "passive" device (with the suitable definition of passive).

Comment: Time reversal symmetry generally prevents it. Now, for a polarized beam one gets some of the way with a polarizer and Faraday rotator, which happens because the Faraday rotation is not symmetric.

Comment: I wonder if an anti-glare coating on the left but not the right would work. Not 100%, clearly

Comment: @PM2Ring - dupe found...

Comment: One way mirrors are in widespread use. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_mirror